# oracle subquery inside case

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Im trying to fetch a row from a subquery where the subquery fecha is the same as the main query fecha

The error is

```sql
ORA-00904: "F"."HORA_INICIO": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Here is my code

```
SELECT F.FECHA,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(F.CODIGO_DEPORTE)) AS CONTEODEPORTES,
       C.CONTEO AS CONTEO,
       CASE 
         WHEN C.CONTEO IS NULL THEN MIN(F.HORA_INICIO)
         ELSE (SELECT *
                 FROM (SELECT (SELECT NOMBRE_DEPORTE
                                 FROM DEPORTES
                                 WHERE PP.CODIGO_DEPORTE=DEPORTES.CODIGO_DEPORTE) AS NOM
                         FROM PROGRAMACIONES PP 
                         WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA_INICIO, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = 
                                 TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(F.FECHA,'DAY, DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                   || ' ' || F.HORA_INICIO
                         ORDER BY NOM)
                 WHERE ROWNUM=1)
       END AS PRIMER_DEPORTE
  FROM FECHAS F
  FULL OUTER JOIN CONTEO C
    ON (F.FECHA=C.FECHA AND
        F.HORA_INICIO=C.HORA_INICIO)
  GROUP BY F.FECHA,C.CONTEO
  ORDER BY TO_DATE(F.FECHA,'DAY, DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY')
```

My problem is when trying to use F.FECHA it does not found the main query

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the types of the fields: `FECHAS.FECHA` and `FECHAS.HORA_INICIO` and `PROGRAMACIONES.FECHA_INICIO` ?

Comment: Fecha is just the date part of a DATE field HORA_INICIO is the time part of a DATE field and FECHA_INICIO is the same as fecha @JorgeCampos

Comment: And what is the version of your oracle?

Comment: @JorgeCampos i think its 12 and i just edited my post including the error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on your case statement subquery. Oracle won't understand the `F.FECHA` field on more than one level for a sub-query and you have 2. Since you said that your Oracle version is 12 it may be possible do what you want with the following modification on your query:

```
SELECT F.FECHA,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(F.CODIGO_DEPORTE)) AS CONTEODEPORTES,
       C.CONTEO AS CONTEO,
       CASE 
         WHEN C.CONTEO IS NULL THEN MIN(F.HORA_INICIO)
         ELSE (  SELECT NOMBRE_DEPORTE
                   FROM DEPORTES D
                          INNER JOIN PROGRAMACIONES PP 
                                ON (D.CODIGO_DEPORTE = PP.CODIGO_DEPORTE)
                  WHERE TO_CHAR(PP.FECHA_INICIO, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = 
                        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(F.FECHA, 
                                        'DAY, DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY'
                                       ),
                                'YYYY-MM-DD'
                                ) || ' ' || F.HORA_INICIO
                  ORDER BY PP.NOM
                  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
         ) END AS PRIMER_DEPORTE
  FROM FECHAS F
  FULL OUTER JOIN CONTEO C
    ON (F.FECHA=C.FECHA AND
        F.HORA_INICIO=C.HORA_INICIO)
  GROUP BY F.FECHA,C.CONTEO
  ORDER BY TO_DATE(F.FECHA,'DAY, DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY')
```

Since you didn't provide any data so we can see what you need it is not possible to give you hints about what could be done to make this query better. And I'm sure that it could be written in a better way if we could understand the data.

**Note** that I just changed your query so the sub-query in the `CASE` statement just have one level, therefore you will be able to reach `F.FECHA` inside it.

**EDIT**

Since you are in Oracle 11g and it doesn't support the `FETCH` clause this would be a workaround. I've added your subquery as a table and used a analytical function to get only one row.

```
SELECT F.FECHA,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(F.CODIGO_DEPORTE)) AS CONTEODEPORTES,
       C.CONTEO AS CONTEO,
       CASE 
         WHEN C.CONTEO IS NULL THEN MIN(F.HORA_INICIO)
         ELSE (ND.NOMBRE_DEPORTE) END AS PRIMER_DEPORTE
  FROM FECHAS F
       FULL OUTER JOIN CONTEO C  
             ON (    F.FECHA=C.FECHA 
                 AND F.HORA_INICIO=C.HORA_INICIO)
        INNER JOIN (SELECT NOMBRE_DEPORTE, 
                           TO_CHAR(PP.FECHA_INICIO, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as FECHA_INICIO,
                           ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by NOMBRE_DEPORTE,
                                                  TO_CHAR(PP.FECHA_INICIO, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                               ORDER BY PP.NOM) as RNUMBER
                      FROM DEPORTES D
                            INNER JOIN PROGRAMACIONES PP 
                                    ON (D.CODIGO_DEPORTE = PP.CODIGO_DEPORTE)
                    ) ND ON ( ND.FECHA_INICIO = TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(F.FECHA, 
                                                                 'DAY, DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY'),
                                                        'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || F.HORA_INICIO
                              AND ND.RNUMBER = 1 )
  GROUP BY F.FECHA, C.CONTEO
  ORDER BY TO_DATE(F.FECHA,'DAY, DD "de" MONTH "de" YYYY')
```

Comment: Hi,@JorgeCampos now its saying that there is a right parenthesis missin but if I remove the order and fetch it works an idea here?? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your oracle is 12? try it without only the FETCH clause please.

Comment: Im so sorry just checked using V$VERSION says its 11g, does it change a lot?

Comment: Unfortunatelly yes, Oracle 11g doesn't support the FETCH clause. I will try another thing. Wait a bit.

Comment: Does it worked? If so, consider in accepting it :) ! Click on the V icon on the left side.